# Using Sleep with findstr in a .bat

Tags: sleep, findstr

I created a .bat file with the below lines

```
cd C:\MyFolder
d:
findstr "Apple" C:\log.txt |findstr "red" > red_apples.txt
SLEEP 3600
GOTO START
```

When the bat is executed, the SLEEP is not working and the commands are running continously.

Is there anything wrong with the code? Please help !

Comment: what is sleep? Its not here on my windows 7 system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Windows has a `sleep`, you can emulate it with `ping`, as shown in this example `chkwait.cmd` script:

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off
    echo %time%
    call :waitfor 20
    echo %time%
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:waitfor
    setlocal
    set /a "t = %1 + 1"
    >nul ping 127.0.0.1 -n %t%
    endlocal
    goto :eof
```

The `call :waitfor 20` in the above script will wait for twenty seconds:

```
pax> chkwait
10:18:13.42
10:18:33.51
```

Answer (score 0):

SLEEP does not exist in windows batch script.  You would have create your own Sleep wrapper EXE and call that from the batch.  Or use the clever trick from @paxdiablo above.